# I can't mutate my current state in redux reducer, even after dispatching an action and passing the exact payload that I need to the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

This is inside my reducer.js

```js
export const initialState = {
  data: [],
};

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action, "ACTIOn");
  switch (action.type) {
    case "FETCH_NEWS":
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

This is my News.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useStateValue } from "../StateProvider";
import axios from "axios";

function News() {
  const [{ data }, dispatch] = useStateValue();
  const [news, setNews] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos").then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data);
      dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_NEWS",
        payload: res.data,
      });
      setNews(data);
      console.log(news, "NUAKJSDAILSGDL");
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="App-header">
        <h1>{news}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default News;
```

My StateProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

//Prepare the dataLayer
export const StateContext = createContext();

// Wrap our app and provide the Data Layer to every component
export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

// Pull Information from the Data Layer
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

The `console.log` gives me the correct order of the action which is `FETCH_NEWS` and an Array of objects. When I try to set the data to the action payload, the data is not updated and when I try to console log my `news` after using react hook to update it with the data from the store, it is empty!

Comment: can you also paste whats in StateProvider

Comment: You can now check my StateProvider, I've just added it! please have a look and let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

State works like a snapshot, so the `data` inside the axios callback is empty.  Thus, setting `news` to data will also be empty. So instead of your current implementation, just directly use `data` in your jsx instead. Remember that when mutating your state via reducer, the updated state will only be available on the next render which did not happen on your case since you did not use the `data` directly. If you do, it should work. It is also redundant to use `useState` with something that is already a state

Comment: what If I want to apply logic like auto complete search or pagination, would that still work with a reducer or is it just simplier to use a state in my news ui just to apply logic functions!